# Passing a subarray to a Fortran subroutine

Tags: fortran

I have created a Fortran array, say

```
real, dimension(4, 4) :: A
```

Being a matrix

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

And I want to pass it to a subroutine in form

```
call MySoubroutine(A(2,2))
```

And inside my subroutine get this array and modify some of its elements

```
real, dimension(:), intent(inout) : A

A(1,1) = 91
A(1, 2) = 92
A(2, 1) = 93
A(2, 2) = 94
```

So after calling the function in my main program the array `A` is

```
1  2  3  4
5  91 92 8
9  93 94 12
13 14 15 16
```

What is the best an most optimum way to achieve such a behaviour?

In detail my questions are:

- Is there a better way of using a subarray inside the subroutine?
- How shall I declare the array in the subroutine? I want just to pass a pointer to the first element, so may not know the dimension of the subarray.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fortran pointer to smaller dimension array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47582640/fortran-pointer-to-smaller-dimension-array)

Comment: @francescalus I am not seeking for a reduction on the rank of the array, but taking an array and being able of modifying a part of it using new indexes. Additionally, in this question there is know code explaining how should I declare the array as input in the subroutine.

Comment: Changing the rank isn't the significant part of the other question, to apply here.  You can pass the array section `A(2:3,2:3)` to a dummy argument of shape `[2,2]` (or an assumed shape rank-2 array).